# Excel shut down when I try open Macro

Tags: excel, vba

One of my excel (excel A) shut down, when I try View Macro. I have enable all macros and when I try view macro from another workbook (when excel A is closed) I can. But when I have open Excel A I can not look on any macro in any workbook. It always shut down all workbooks I have open. I edit excel A 5 day ago and it works fine.
Any idea how to fix it? 
I already try reset PC, open from empty excel (open and repair, open read only, ...) Nothing helps

Comment: Force close of Excel is either a Bug in Excel, a corrupt Excel installation or a corrupt file. Test if the file works in another computer (if that works your Excel installation is corrupt). If it force closes on other computers too, either Excel has a bug or your file is corrupted. Since other files work, it is likely that your file is corrupted. Files can most likely not be repaired and need to be rebuilt from scratch. What you can try is to safe the file in the binary `xlsb` format. This might fix it or not. `xlsb` is known to be much more stable against file corruption.

Comment: If you do need an answer - share files. There are no magicians here.

Comment: Last option: Use a backup of your file that worked.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Actually we don't share files on Stack Overflow. No one here will open a file from a suspect source that can contain excecutable code. That is one reason why you cannot upload files on Stack Overflow. • Instead everything that is needed to understand the question has to be in the question itself according to [ask].

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I know that. But when I post such comment - I don't make anyone else open files, and assume my own risks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for help. At the end i fix it this way.
Open and Repair and choose Extract Data. I have to add macro buttons again, but I can view and modify macro codes :)

Comment: So that means your file was corrupt. I recommend to stick to the binary `xlsb` format if you can (which can contain macros too). Actually I never use `xlsx` or `xlsm` unless I have to, as I got too many times file corruptions that could not be repaired. `xlsb` is much more solid.